# Bootstrap validation not working on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

So I am new to bootstrap and so far I've got everything working the way I want. I have created a contact form which uses the Modal Form and sends the email via PHP using the Mail function.

I have created a script to do the validation on the form. If the validation passes I want the email to be sent out.

Currently when the user submits the form that is blank the validation isn't working and the email is getting sent.

Please keep in mind I'm am new to working with bootstrap.

HTML

```
<div id="ContactUs" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Contact Us</h4>
                <p><b>XXXX</b><br>
                    Company Phone: XXXXX
                </p>
              </div>
              <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="scripts/email.php">
                  <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your full name here.">
                            <label for="name">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email address here.">
                            <label for="name">Subject</label>
                            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your subject here.">
                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your message here."></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Script

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $validator = $("#contactForm").validate({
            errorClass:'error',
            validClass:'success',
            errorElement:'span',
            highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
$(element).parents("div[class='clearfix']").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
            }, 
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) { 
    $(element).parents(".error").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass); 
            },
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: '<span class="help-inline">Your name is required</span>',
                    minlength: jQuery.format('<span class="help-inline">2 chars</span>')
                },
                subject: {
                    required: '<span class="help-inline">A Subject is required.
    </span>',
     minlength:jQuery.format('<span class="help-inline">10 characters</span>')
                },
                email: {
                    required: '<span class="help-inline">Email.</span>',
                    email: '<span class="help-inline">Ex : name@exemple.com</span>'
                },
                message: {
                    required: '<span class="help-block">Message</span>',
                    minlength: jQuery.format('<span class="help-block">10 chars</span>')
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) 
            {
                $('form').submit(function() {
                    if ($validator.numberOfInvalids() > 0) 
                    {
                        $('#submit').modal('hide');
                    } else 
                    {
                        $('#submit').modal('show');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: In the input fields just put 'required'

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive with your answer?

required=""?

Comment: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="." required />

Comment: I tried it and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

On each input field add 'required'. Simple way to ensure each field has data

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" action="scripts/email.php">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your full name here." required />
                                <label for="name">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email address here." required />
                                <label for="name">Subject</label>
                                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your subject here." required />
                                <label for="message">Message</label>
                                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your message here." required /></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                  </form>
```

Comment: I did that and the form still submits and no validation occurs.

Comment: Then your script is messing with the validation, remove it and validate in php before the mail is sent.

Comment: I thought about doing that but I want to get the other bootstrap validation working as it looks better visually.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already include jquery and validation library?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass your form to your button with attribute
`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="ContactUs">Submit</button>`
you should put your form id inside that